# Radius Of convergence using Cauchy Hadamard Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n(n+1)}z^{2n^2}$$.

**My approach**

By using Cauchy-Hadamard formula, I am getting the radius of convergence, R=0.

Comment: Note that the coefficients of your given series occur only in the $2n^2$-th positions.

Comment: Is my answer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see: $r=1/(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n^2]{2^{n(n+1)}})=1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: No.  $2^{n(n+1)}$ is the coefficient of the $2n^2$-term.

Comment: yeah, I got your point. Thanks!